# Convert XmlSerializer class to protobuf-net usage

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

Currently I am experimenting using protobuf-net with C#.
I have a class that is Serialized using System.Xml.Serialization;

```
[XmlType(Namespace="http://www.test.com")]
[XmlRoot(Namespace="http://www.test.com", ElementName="message", IsNullable=false)]
public class TestMessage 
{
    /// <remarks/>
    [XmlAttribute(Form=XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string specificationversion;

    [XmlElement("errornotification", typeof(errorNotificationfType))]

    [XmlIgnore()]
    public bool ProductCodeSpecified;

    public string SubText;

    [XmlElement(DataType = "hexBinary")]
    public List<byte[]> Index;

    [XmlAttribute()]
    public bool Complete;

    public object Item;

    /// <remarks/>
    public InfoType info;
}
```

Now I want to convert this part to be used with protobuf-net.

I have seen some examples and started with:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class TestMessage 
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    ....
    ....
}
```

Now I am stuck. Can somebody help me to convert this class? And what should I do with the XmlType, XmlRoot, XmlAttribute, XmlElement and XmlIgnore parts?

Comment: You might want to try a little more and show the exact problems you're having rather than just coming and asking someone else to do it all for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can ignore those, by the looks of it `Protobuf` does not have attributes, elements, root or namespaces so all of those become  `ProtoMember`.

```
[ProtoContract]
public class TestMessage 
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string specificationversion;

    // ignore
    public bool ProductCodeSpecified;

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string SubText;

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public List<byte[]> Index;

    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public bool Complete;

    public object Item;

    [ProtoMember(5)]
    public InfoType info;
}
```

There are some good examples [here](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/GettingStarted).

Comment: Thanks!  I am gonna give it a try.